# Call yield from another do ...end block

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I try to define own 'context' method in Rspec.
Have next:

```
module MiscSpecHelper
  def its_ok
    context "if everything is OK" do
      yield
    end
  end
end
```

in spec file:

```
describe "GET index" do
  its_ok do
    it "has a 200 status code" do
      get :index
      expect(response.status).to eq(200)
    end
  end
end
```

I got:

```
GET index
  has a 200 status code
```

I expect:

```
GET index
  if everything is OK
    has a 200 status code
```

Why does it ignore my 'context' description?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
module MiscSpecHelper
  def its_ok(&block)
    context "if everything is OK", &block
  end
end
```